# How can I prevent a CMake external project from updating & reinstalling whenever I make?

Tags: cmake, external-project

After much agony, I've successfully arranged for my CMake project to use some library via ExternalProject. I `cmake`, I `make`, it works - life is good.

However, if I `make` again, it performs the Update and Install steps for the external project. I definitely do *not* want this to happen. How do I prevent this?

Answer (score 2):

While the way you proposed in your own answer has the same effect, the actual option you might want to use for that is `UPDATE_DISCONNECTED`.

From [CMake's documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/ExternalProject.html), under the section **Update/patch options**:
`UPDATE_DISCONNECTED <bool>`

> When enabled, this option causes the update step to be skipped. It does not, however, prevent the download step. The update step can still be added as a step target (see `ExternalProject_Add_StepTargets()`) and called manually.

So your final thing could look like the following:

```
ExternalProject_Add( external_lib
    # ...
    UPDATE_DISCONNECTED True
)
```

If you go a bit further down the excerpt I quoted though, the documentation explicitly advises against doing this and recommends controlling the update behaviour through a directory variable `EP_UPDATE_DISCONNECTED`, whose value is used as the default value for `UPDATE_DISCONNECTED`.
This means you can keep your `ExternalProject_Add` call free of the `UPDATE_DISCONNECTED` option, and instead run your CMake command like so:

```
$ cmake .. -DEP_UPDATE_DISCONNECTED:BOOL=True
$ cmake --build . [your_options]
```

Comment: what's the difference between `UPDATE_DISCONNECTED 1` and `UPDATE_COMMAND ""`  ?

Comment: `UPDATE_COMMAND ""` makes the update step a no-op essentially, but CMake might or might not still be doing update-related stuff at this step. `UPDATE_DISCONNECTED 1` disables the update step entirely.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to set `UPDATE_COMMAND` to `""` for your library's external project, that is, have:

```
ExternalProject_Add(the_external_library_proj_name
    # all sorts of settings here
    # etc. etc.
    # ...
    UPDATE_COMMAND ""
)
```

in your `CMakeLists.txt`. That means you might not be able to update the external project via CMake and will have to resort to doing it manually, or cleanly rebuilding everything etc.